How to feed a Facebook page to a website without requiring viewer to log into Facebook
I'm looking at creating a company news portal that would pull in the social media posts for the company.
I would like to start with Facebook, but would eventually include others like instagram, linkedin, etc.
Since this portal would be accessible by corporately  own machines I would like to minimize the need to have people log directly onto Facebook to see the company page, since I would like to minimize the potential security impact.
Any webpage plug-ins, etc. that would meet the need?
Thanks!
I looked at the Meta html generation to read a page, but it asks for a log in - would like to avoid that, I can't really seem to find anything else that would work

If the functionality https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin provides is enough for you, you can use that. Otherwise, you'll have to feed the post content via API, and render it yourself. That doesn't need every single page viewer to log in, you can use a page access token on the server side.
